# Xamarin Forms Custom Datagrid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, datagrid, syncfusion

I have a model as you can see in the attachment. I can get output in datagrid itemsource  as shown (syncfusion sfDataGrid). but I want to get output like below. how can I do it?

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMxAt.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve this you can :

1- the best way is to replace your sfDataGrid with syncfusion PivodGrid.

2- Or if you want to achieve it with a datagrid, you have to transform your data collection according to, each element in the collection is a row so you have to make group by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I guess pivotgrid is not available in syncfusion.
I will try the 2nd way.

Comment: no, pivot table is available in syncfusion , see this demo : https://github.com/syncfusion/wpf-demos/tree/master/pivotgrid

Comment: This is wpf but my project Xamarin.Forms. Can I use?

Comment: Sorry i missed this detail, no you are right it's not available for xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a sample to achieve your requirement. Please refer to the following code snippets to achieve the requirement,

XAML: Define Columns and rows using GridUnboundColumn and UnboundRows respectively.

```
<sfgrid:SfDataGrid x:Name="sfGrid"

            ColumnSizer="Star"

            AutoGenerateColumns="False"

            ItemsSource="{Binding OrdersInfo}">

 

    <sfgrid:SfDataGrid.Behaviors>

        <local:DataGridBehavior/>

    </sfgrid:SfDataGrid.Behaviors>

 

    <sfgrid:SfDataGrid.Columns>

        <sfgrid:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Color" MappingName="Color" />

 

        <sfgrid:GridUnboundColumn MappingName="S" HeaderText="S"/>

        <sfgrid:GridUnboundColumn MappingName="M" HeaderText="M"/>

        <sfgrid:GridUnboundColumn MappingName="L" HeaderText="L"/>

        <sfgrid:GridUnboundColumn MappingName="XL" HeaderText="XL"/>

        <sfgrid:GridUnboundColumn MappingName="2XL" HeaderText="2XL"/>

    </sfgrid:SfDataGrid.Columns>

 

    <sfgrid:SfDataGrid.UnboundRows>

        <sfgrid:GridUnboundRow />

        <sfgrid:GridUnboundRow />

    </sfgrid:SfDataGrid.UnboundRows>

</sfgrid:SfDataGrid>
```

Behavior: In the SfDataGrid.QueryUnboundRow event, set the value based on the model object. Also, hide the actual data rows using the QueryRowHeight event.

```
public class DataGridBehavior : Behavior<SfDataGrid>
{

    SfDataGrid DataGrid;

 

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(SfDataGrid bindable)

    {

        DataGrid = bindable;

        DataGrid.QueryUnboundRow += sfGrid_QueryUnboundRow;

        DataGrid.QueryRowHeight += sfGrid_QueryRowHeight;

        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

    }

 

    private void sfGrid_QueryUnboundRow(object sender, GridUnboundRowEventArgs e)

    {

       var viewModel = (sender as SfDataGrid).BindingContext as ViewModel;

        if (e.UnboundAction == UnboundActions.QueryData)

        {

            List<Orders> rowOrders = null;

 

            if (e.RowColumnIndex.RowIndex == 1)

            {

                rowOrders = viewModel.OrdersInfo.Where(x => x.Color == "WHITE").ToList();

            }

            else if (e.RowColumnIndex.RowIndex == 2)

            {

                rowOrders = viewModel.OrdersInfo.Where(x => x.Color == "BLACK").ToList();

            }

 

            if (e.RowColumnIndex.ColumnIndex == 0)

            {

                e.Value = rowOrders[0].Color;

                e.Handled = true;

            }

            else

            {

                var item = rowOrders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Size == e.Column.HeaderText.ToString());

                e.Value = item != null ? item.Stock.ToString() : "-";

                e.Handled = true;

            }

        }

    }

 

 

    private void sfGrid_QueryRowHeight(object sender, QueryRowHeightEventArgs e)

    {

        if (e.RowIndex == 0)

        {

            e.Height = 50;

        }

 

        //To hide the actual data rows from the view.

        else if (!DataGrid.IsUnboundRow(e.RowIndex))

        {

            e.Height = 0;

            e.Handled = true;

        }

    }

}
```

Please find the workable sample in the following link.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/GettingStarted-549596453

You can refer to our user guidance document regarding UnboundRows and UnboundColumns from the following link,

UG links:

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/unbound-column

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/unbound-row#populating-data-for-unbound-rows

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/row-height-customization#customize-rowheight-for-all-rows

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but as I mentioned above, I preferred the 2nd way and developed it myself.